# Using Multiple CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am getting duplicate results for each CTE as I am using Group BY for Months Data. This is a part of the query where is the problem. There are calculation on the basis for Columns created on CTEs.
Please help with this...

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
SET @StartDate='12/01/2012'
WHILE @StartDate<'12/02/2012' --Set GETDATE()
BEGIN
WITH CTE3 (Parameter,Month3,Count3,Count2,Count1,DateRange,OrgID)    
 AS    
  (    
  SELECT CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(50)) Parameter
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRange=CAST(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(M,0,@StartDate),0)),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YYYY,@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(50))
  THEN Col2 else 0 END) Month3
  ,(SELECT COUNT(Col1) FROM [Table_Name] 
  WHERE Col1='INS Charges'   
  AND DateRange = CAST(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(M,0,@StartDate),0)),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YYYY,@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(50))) Count3
  ,(SELECT COUNT(Col1) FROM [Table_Name]
  WHERE DateRange = CAST(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(M,0,@StartDate)-1,0)),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YYYY,@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(50))) Count2  
  ,(SELECT COUNT(Col1) FROM [Table_Name]   
  WHERE DateRange = CAST(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(M,0,@StartDate)-2,0)),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YYYY,@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(50))) Count1  
  ,DateRange
  ,OrgID
  FROM [Table_Name]
  WHERE DateRange=CAST(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(M,0,@StartDate),0)),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YYYY,@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(50))
  GROUP BY Col1,OrgID,DateRange
  )
  ,CTE2 (Parameter,Month2,DateRange,OrgID)
  AS
  (
    SELECT CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(50)) Parameter
    ,SUM(Col2) Month2
    ,DateRange
    ,OrgID
    from [Table_Name]
    WHERE DateRange= CAST(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(M,0,@StartDate)-1,0)),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YYYY,@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(50))
    GROUP BY Col1,OrgID,DateRange
  )
  ,CTE1 (Parameter,Month1,DateRange,OrgID)
  AS
  (
    SELECT CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(50)) Parameter
    ,SUM(Col2) Month1
    ,DateRange
    ,OrgID
    from [Table_Name]
    WHERE DateRange= CAST(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(M,0,@StartDate)-2,0)),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YYYY,@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(50))
    GROUP BY Col1,DateRange,OrgID
  )
  SELECT CTE3.Parameter    
  ,CTE1.Month1
  ,CTE2.Month2    
  ,CTE3.Month3
  ,CTE1.Month1+CTE2.Month2+CTE3.Month3 YTD
  ,(CTE1.Month1+CTE2.Month2+CTE3.Month3)/3 [3 Month Avg]
  ,Cte3.OrgID
  ,Cte3.DateRange
  FROM CTE3
  JOIN CTE1 ON CTE1.Parameter=CTE3.Parameter
  JOIN CTE2 ON CTE2.Parameter=CTE3.Parameter
  SET @StartDate=(SELECT DATEADD(M,1,@StartDate))
  END
```

Sample Data

Table_Name

---

```
Col1  | Col2  | OrgID | DateRange|
ABC1  |100    |1      |Jan-2014  |
ABC2  |200    |2      |Feb-2014  |
ABC1  |300    |3      |Jan-2014  |
ABC2  |400    |1      |Feb-2014  |
ABC1  |100    |2      |Mar-2014  |
ABC2  |200    |3      |Mar-2014  |
--------------------------------------
```

This is a report for last 3 months which contains complex calculations. If you can notice the table_Name just contain the DateRange on a basis of which I have to create Last 3 Months data in the columns and according to the data which the above query fetches (i.e. Month1, Month2 etc), have to perform mathematical operations. That is why I have choosen CTE.

I am able to generate the results but the only problem is getting duplicate rows per column as Each CTE has Group By.

If any alternative is their please let me know!!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: could you create a new procedure in which includes all functionality required? if yes, share procedure code.

Comment: @Horaciux: Please check the edited query.

Comment: Could you add some sample data for the table Table_Name?

Comment: I have updated the sample data!!! Hope it helps

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What results did you expect? Whatever it is, this query seems to be way too complicated. Besides, the multiple scans of the same table, string manipulation etc will result in very bad performance

Comment: That is going to be a Job. not looking much about performance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Casting is done just because to match the Date Range as you can see in the Sample table. And other casting is done  as this data has to be dumped in some other table.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably JOIN the CTE-s on each of the columns in their GROUP BY clauses, such as:

```
FROM CTE3
JOIN CTE1 ON CTE1.Parameter=CTE3.Parameter AND CTE1.OrgID=CTE3.OrgID AND CTE1.DateRange=CTE3.DateRange
JOIN CTE2 ON CTE2.Parameter=CTE3.Parameter AND CTE2.OrgID=CTE3.OrgID AND CTE2.DateRange=CTE3.DateRange
```

(assuming those columns do not allow NULLs)